# Debug Issue VS Code

Tags: c++

I'm having this error while debugging in VS Code.

> '"C:\Windows\system32\bash.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or
> external command, operable program or batch file. Command failed:
> "C:\Windows\system32\bash.exe" "-c" "sh -c 'uname && if [ $(uname) =
> "Linux" ] ; then ps axww -o
> pid=,comm=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,args= ;
> elif [ $(uname) = "Darwin" ] ; then ps axww -o
> pid=,comm=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,args= -c;
> fi'" '"C:\Windows\system32\bash.exe"' is not recognized as an internal
> or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Switch your terminal to use cmd.exe or powershell.

Comment: Look at ['bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1598#issuecomment-272688175)